# "Cannot load libcuda.so.1" when running ffmpeg with hardware acceleration on WSL2 Windows

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, wsl2

I am following [NVIDIA's](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/) doc for building ffmpeg with hardware acceleration capabilities. I have also installed the appropriate [driver for my GeForce GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl/download) and did the [CUDA toolkit setup for WSL2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#ch03a-setting-up-cuda). I am trying specifically to run the following command, after configuring ffmpeg like so:

#### Configuration (identical to the linux section of the doc)

```
./configure --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --disable-static --enable-shared
```

#### Command (same as [this section](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/#command-line-for-low-latency-transcoding) of the doc)

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p6 -tune ll -b:v 5M -bufsize 5M -maxrate 10M -qmin 0 -g 250 -bf 3 -b_ref_mode middle -temporal-aq 1 -rc-lookahead 20 -i_qfactor 0.75 -b_qfactor 1.1 output.mp4
```

#### The problem:

[image: problem]

Is there anything that I am missing? I tried running `sudo find / -name libcuda.so.1` but could not find this .so file on a WSL 2 folder, only inside Windows' `/mnt` folders. I have also downloaded, but not installed, the [video codec SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk/download) but I am not sure if it is required at all since it is not mentioned on the doc I am following.

Answer (score 0):

When installed correctly, `libcuda.so.1` should be at `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` inside wsl2.

All you need to do is to add the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so it can by dynamically loaded, like

```sh
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/wsl/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}' >> ~/.bashrc
```